# sed command difference in behaviour between each OS and its implication

Tags: shell, unix, command-line, posix

I have come across a strange but valid difference between the working behavior of `sed` command. To be frank this has come as a very big surprise to me.

Now let us look at the man pages of `sed` of SUSE Linux and HP (IA64).

---

**SUSE Linux:**

> DESCRIPTION
>          Sed  is a stream editor.  A stream editor is used to perform basic text
>          transformations on an input stream (a file or input from  a  pipeline).
>          While  in  some  ways similar to an editor which permits scripted edits
>          (such as ed), sed works by making only one pass over the input(s),  and
>          is consequently more efficient.  But it is sed's ability to filter text
>          in a pipeline which particularly distinguishes it from other  types  of
>          editors.

---

**HP IA64 :**

> DESCRIPTION
>   sed copies the named text files (standard input default) to the standard output, edited according to a script containing up to 100 commands. Only complete input lines are processed. **Any input text at the end of a file that is not terminated by a new-line character is ignored**

The highlighted text, seems to be a major difference in working behavior. So all my scripts started failing in the HP-UX IA64 machine during porting.

Question :
a. Isn't there any underlying standard that force each vendor to have basic conformity with the implementation?

b. In case there are some commands which confirm and others which cannot confirm, can anyone post the list that adhere to standards.

c. Now I have a lot of such command that are used as part of my project scripting. What is the best way to check/avoid such kind of error - apart from testing each and every command for all scenario?

Basically In such scenario I would be facing problem confirming software *working for all scenarios* across vendor platforms.

Comment: that limit of 100 commands to a script seems rather abritrary too! I've mostly worked in a Solaris environment (and some AIX), which are limited compared to the GNU tools of Linux, but as I used to read the news groups, it seemed like HP unix always had more *opportunities* for recoding than anything else. Do you know about POSIX definitions for Unix tools? Doesn't mean that HP has to follow them. Add a Posix tag and maybe a real Posix guru will have some real answers for you. Good luck.

Comment: The underlying standard says that lines in text files shall end with newlines; anything that doesn't meet that leads to undefined behaviour.  Don't use `sed` on files that don't end with a newline; it is not portable - as you've just found out the hard way!

Comment: The variation between different versions of `sed` are legion.  This is one of the things which makes it hard to write a portable shell script.  A practical workaround might be to convert your `sed` scripts to Perl; the Perl distribution comes with a utility `s2p` which does this automatically.  Of course, Perl is not even formally specified, but it is portable due to there being only a single implementation.  (You might still end up with corner cases where different versions behave differently, but probably not in scripts generated by `s2p`.)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

From a POSIX perspective, nothing is wrong with the HP-UX behaviour of ignoring text after the last newline. The key is in the requirement on the application that `sed`'s input files be text files. This means that there may not be any NUL bytes, line length is limited to {LINE_MAX} (including the newline) and the file must end with a newline if it is not empty (because a line must end in a newline). If the application calls `sed` with an input file that is not a text file, the behaviour is undefined.

Other common behaviours for this situation include running the script with a "line" that does not end in a newline (GNU sed) and adding a final newline if one is missing (FreeBSD sed).

The limit of 100 commands seems more questionable; I do not see a sentence that allows such a limit.

POSIX.1-2008 references: XBD 3.205 Line, XBD 3.394 Text File, XCU 4 Utilities sed.

Comment: Your answer was very useful.Can you post a link where these are mentioned as part of POSIX (Did google - could not find the answer). I want to verify the standard and prepare a checklist for the project.

Comment: http://pubs.opengroup.org/onlinepubs/007904875/utilities/sed.html is the top Google hit for the search "posix sed".